# JavaFX 2.0 and Qt for cross-platform application

Tags: java, c++, qt, cross-platform, javafx-2

I need a bit of advice from you developers who deal with cross-platform applications (specifically programs with a GUI).

I will be creating an application soon that needs to be cross-platform and so I have done some preliminary research on two different frameworks: JavaFX 2.0 and Qt.

Honestly, both would more than suit my needs. So then I asked myself why I would choose one over the other (SPOILER ALERT: I don't know the answer :P ). I do know that JavaFX 2.0 is rather new (as of 2012) and is not fully supported across platforms, but it will be eventually.

The question I pose is this: which one of these would you use for a cross-platform application, and what criteria did you look at when making that decision?

Thank you for taking the time to read this! :)

**EDIT:**
For your reference when considering this question, the application I will be writing involves reading/writing XML files, displaying images, and creating some small widgets with custom functionality.  I've written a similar application in C# with .NET, but would like advice when considering JavaFX 2.0 or Qt for cross-platform usability.

Thanks again!  :)

Comment: Swing, but it comes down to exactly what it is you're trying to achieve. Cross-platform is quite enough to make a determination on

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree that the ability to be cross-platform is enough to make a decision.  Both JavaFX 2 and Qt are cross-platform and they both seem to be rather easy to develop with.  I have used Swing in Java, but only briefly.  Do you prefer Swing to JavaFX 2 or Qt?

Comment: I prefer Swing because it's what I know.  I also know there are a lot of really good, open source, API's for it. Hence the problem. Without know what it is you hope to achieve it's difficult to make a suggestion.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you!  I've updated my question to include a high-level view of the types of activities that the application will include.  None of it is overly complex and I have done a very similar application (as well as several other non-similar applications) in C#.  This is just the first time I have experienced the need to be cross-platform.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Hm, personally, I would not recommend Swing for a new project. I think JavaFX is more consistent, easy-to-use and feature-rich than Swing and will see much support from Oracle in the future. Swing on the other hand is pretty much dying.

Comment: you can also take a look at Electron framework if you want a cross platform application with reach UI capabilities.It uses Html as UI structure and javascript as primary language.Even more, you can use visual studio code as a strong and professional tool for developing and debugging your Electron apps.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's the old question: stability vs bleeding edge. I'll try to give you some personal insights based on your application features.

> JavaFX 2.0 is rather new (as of 2012) and is not fully supported across platforms

Well, it's fully supported on Linux, Windows and Mac. I can say that because I'm developing a JavaFX 2.2 application in Mac which the server runs on a Linux box and the clients on Windows boxes.

> Reading/writing XML files

I'm yet to see some tool/interface better/easier/faster than sax2 to parse XML. Of course QtXMLPatterns module parser deservers respect but they are even developing a SAX2 based XML parser (Which by the way is not complete and not fully compatible with legacy SAX1 methods) so I would say that add JavaFX 2 some score.

> Displaying images

Both technologies can display images with enough ease, but JavaFX 2.2 lacks some tools for **image manipulation** (Specially format codecs). If image processing is a critical matter, I would say that Qt is slight up ahead in the fight.

> creating some small widgets with custom functionality.

As of now, this is not an easy task in JavaFX 2 since the Stage object does not have an option like ALWAYS_ON_TOP and won't have until 3.0 (Somewhere in 2013) It's not impossible tough, but Qt already has some nice tools for customize/display/handle widgets that we simply can not reproduce in JavaFX.

> which one of these would you use for a cross-platform application, and what criteria did you look at when making that decision?

Well, JavaFX 2.2 is made of and for Java. I personally find to program in Java a lot better and easy than C++. You'll never have to struggle with pointers in java, you can always rely on the Garbage Collector for memory management, there are a plenty of tutorials and documentation across the web (which I believe surpasses C++) and an always growing Java Gurus community.

In abstract, I've choose JavaFX 2.2 because it's pretty, because it's cool, because I can handle the MVC more easily and because I love Java, but I believe you should go for Qt if the widget part of your application is the main purpose of it.

I hope it helped, cheers

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer, Bruno!  I do think that I would like to know both, but for this coming project I think I will go with JavaFX 2.2 (yay bleeding edge!).  Thank you!

Answer (score 13):

I'm currently researching various cross-platform frameworks suitable for developing an offline html5 authoring application. Beyond cross-platform operation (Windows, Linux, OS-X), my app also has these major requirements:

Embedded database
Embedded (or, secondarily, a mainstream browser) HTML5 rendering engine
High-functioning editable DND tree, splitter panel, and rich text editor widgets
Medium-duty image processing
USB stick portability

I've taken a serious look at these frameworks:

jQuery (JavaScript), HTML5, CSS3
Google Web Toolkit [GWT] (Java to JavaScript)
JavaFX 2.0 (Java)
QT (C++ (Java binding available))
Xulrunner (XML, JavaScript)
GTK+ (C)
Adobe Air
Pyjamas

I've spent a minor fortune on books for all these technologies, and I've begun coding prototypes to see how fast and how far each framework could take me.

Initially, JavaFX 2.0 took me furthest the fastest, by a big margin. The simple explanation for this is, with JavaFX, all the tools, IDEs, libraries, documentation, code examples, turnarounds, debugging, community support, manufacturer (Oracle) support, and learning curves came together with the least amount of impedance mismatching.

Probably JavaFX's biggest win was it's ease of implementing a client-side embedded database (Derby). With all the other frameworks, this task was, surprisingly, considerably more difficult and 'kludgy.'

Unfortunately, I ran into a serious JavaFX stumbling block when I discovered the WebView widget does not execute JavaScript from local file:// URLs. QtWebKit, GTKWebKit, Safari, and Opera (all WebKit based) also exhibit the same file:// JavaScript blocking behavior (however Chrome does not), so I surmise this is a default WebKit security measure.

At the time, I considered the file:// JavaScript problem a JavaFX showstopper so I moved on to developing jQuery, GWT, and Xulrunner prototypes. As a result, though, my prototyping productivity took a huge nosedive. The Frankensteining and impedance mismatching with these other frameworks was noticeably worse than with JavaFX.

So much so that after many weeks wandering around in the weeds, I returned to my JavaFX prototype highly motivated to find a work around. I eventually solved the problem by embedding Java SE 6's web server in the prototype, and connecting to local files by loading the JavaFX WebEngine with URLs in the following format: "http://localhost:58357/xxxxx.html" Unblocking the JavaFX prototype in this manner was like coming home. It was a real breath of fresh air, not to mention big, big productivity booster.

Based on these experiences, here are some insights that might prove helpful in the JavaFX vs Qt debate.

- I concur with the question of JavaFX vs Qt as those two frameworks respectively ended up being my
  #1 and #2 favorite, most productive choices.
- That said, I'd add the jQuery/HTML5/CSS3 framework into the mix. This
  framework is so strong and so loaded with potential for x-platform
  application development that I'd go so far as to say it's
  inescapable. In my wide-ranging search for widget controls, the
  leading candidates for editable DND tree, splitter panel, and rich
  text wysiwyg editor widgets turned out to be open source jQuery
  plugins. Once you get around the local file:// issue,
  jQuery/HTML5/CSS3 is nicely compatible with the JavaFX WebView
  widget. The one area where jQuery/HTML5/CSS3 falls short is with
  client-side database storage. This is where a combination of JavaFX
  and jQuery/HTML5/CSS3 frameworks is proving to be extremely powerful.
- Even though they're written in C++, Qt modules have Java and
  JavaScript language wrappers meaning developers don't need to know or use
  C++ in order to use Qt.
- This brings up the point that it doesn't have to be a JavaFX vs Qt,
  either-or question. In fact, a more constructive and rewarding
  question could well be, "JavaFX AND Qt?"
- This brings up another important point: I'm quickly discovering my
  best cross-platform application development framework is actually an
  amalgam of JavaFX 2, straight-up Java SE, Swing (for a legacy custom
  widget), WebKit, and jQuery/HTML5/CSS3. Down the road, GWT,
  associated third-party GWT libraries, and Qt modules could
  potentially join the mix. The point here is the plan to use a single,
  genetically pure framework quickly went out the window.
- Currently, the one common thread that binds this entire hybrid
  framework together is plain-old Java SE. And because JavaFX 2 is
  built on Java SE, my vote is to start with JavaFX 2, then add Swing,
  WebKit, jQuery/HTML5/CSS3, GWT, and Qt on an as-needed basis.
- Finally, this article helped convince me to jump on the JavaFX wagon.
  http://fxexperience.com/2012/04/interview-with-peter-zhelezniakov/

--H

Comment: Wow, thank you for this!  You have helped to solidify my decision to use JavaFX for this project.  And perhaps you are right in that it doesn't necessarily have to be looked at as one or the other.  Thanks for the link as well!

Comment: Glad to be of some help. Just found a more elegant way to load a local .html file: convert file name to Java URL object using the getResource() method. Load url.toExternalForm() into the JavaFX WebEngine and voila. Got this tip from the book, "JavaFX 2.0 Introduction by Example", which I think you'll find an excellent investment. The deeper I dig into JavaFX 2, the more I'm convinced it's the RIA bomb.

Comment: Ayaah. Red face. Just prepend "file:/" to filename (note the single forward slash), and call WebEngine.load(file:/xxxxx.html) (versus WebEngine.loadContent()) and JavaScript works great in WebView.

Comment: I also just figured out that the "file:/" is necessary.  I was really confused for a bit.  Glad you have also figured this out!

Comment: I'm wondering wondering if this description is obsolete. My JavaFx runs external js files without issues.

Answer (score 8):

I see from the timestamps it was 4-months ago when I reported I had chosen JavaFX2 over QT for my prototyping research project. About 2-months ago I began switching from JavaFX2 to QT, and haven't looked back since. The main point of contention was transitioning from prototyping to production. For writing production code, QT proved to be miles ahead of JavaFX2.

As always, the devil is in the details, and it was a bunch of little stuff that made a big difference. With JavaFX2, I was constantly confronting and working around little things like uncontrollable splitter-pane resize behavior, limited tree control, and limited WebKit API access (e.g. try implementing browser zoom buttons, or saving an entire web page to a local html file - doable but 100X clunkier than it should be). When added together, these "minor" work-arounds slowed progress to a halt.

With QT, such roadblocks are much less present, and as a result, transitioning from prototype to product has been natural, seamless, and orders of magnitude faster.

On the downside, getting to "Hello World" with QT took much longer. Once there, though, productivity quickly overtook and far surpassed JavaFX2. One reason for this is QT documentation, example programs, and developer community are much more extensive. QT has been around since 1992, JavaFX2 since 2011, and this age difference makes a significant difference in the maturity levels of the two GUI frameworks.

As for the Java vs C++ question, has not been at all an issue. Both are great languages. Personally, for a variety of efficiency, productivity, and performance reasons, I'm finding C++ to be the superior GUI language, but again, that's a personal conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best and the most enjoyable part of Qt is its signal-slot, especially while dealing with threads, it makes it very easy.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from .NET/C#, you should also consider [Real Studio](http://www.realsoftware.com) as a way to create a cross-platform applications. It certainly meets your requirements for what you are trying to create and will be much simpler than JavaFX or Qt.

Comment: Thank you!  I will certainly look into Real Studio before making a final decision.